# Is this 2x4 in my closet load bearing? Can I remove it?

Tags: load-bearing, beam, support, closet

[image]
[image]

Looking to update/open my closet... as it is right now, it's roughly two basic closets side by side with one 2x4 in the middle. With this set up I need two sets of sliding doors... I am hoping to take out the 2x4 so I can use 3 larger sliding doors, thus making the door openings, larger. Above the closet is a primitive attic.

[image]

Thoughts on removing this 2x4?
The black circle is roughly where the 2x4 is below.

[image: The black circle is about where the 2x4 is below]

Comment: Can you add a pic that is zoomed out, showing the entire closet and some of the room around it?  Need more info, but guessing it's not supporting the house structure but maybe supporting or stiffening the closet header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added two more pictures. Apologies for the poor formatting of this post, not tech savvy :)

Comment: Welcome. Take the [tour]. When adding pictures, don't mess with the code the editor inserts, other than carefully editing in a description where it says. Easiest if you enter a blank line, the picture and a blank line after the picture code.

Comment: Thank you! I will look at the tour!!

Comment: Defiantly NOT lead bearing

Comment: Both definitely and even possibly defiantly not load-bearing ;)

Comment: @brhans thanks for your reply! Do you see any issue in removing it?

Comment: @Ruskes thank you for your reply! Do you see any issue in removing it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of the house structure but it may be supporting the closet header from which the new doors will hang.

You will obviously need to patch up the bottom edge of the header for the new track after you remove it as there is a gap; you should also remove some of the drywall and check/improve the header if necessary to support the new doors solidly.